# Let set $A$ be a set of first $5$ natural numbers. Identifying $X, Y$ non-equal, non-empty subsets of $A$ then number of ordered pair with condition

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, combinations

> Suppose set $A$ be a set of first $5$ natural numbers. Identifying $X, Y$ non-equal, non-empty subsets of $A$ then number of (i) Ordered  sets pair of $(X,Y)$ such that $\max(X)>\min(Y)$ is $2^{p}$. Find value of $p$

**My Method:** Insted of solving $\max(X)>\min(Y)$. I tried to calculate $\max(X)\leq \min(Y)$

Let $X=\{1,2,3,...,m\}$ and $\max{X}=m$ and so number of subsets of $X$ containing $m$ is $2^{m-1}$

Let $Y=\{m,{m+1},....,n\}$ and number of non-empty subsets of $(2^{n-m+1}-1)$ because set $Y$ contains $n-m+1$ elements.

Now according to question $m$ can vary from $1$ to $5$

So number of ordered pair $(X,Y)$ is $\sum_{m=1}^{5} 2^{m-1}\cdot {(2^{6-m}-1)}=\sum_{m=1}^{5}2^5-2^{m-1}=129$

And total Number of non-empty ordered pair $(X, Y)$ is $(2^5-1)^2-31=930$

So, Final answer is $930-129=801$ Which can not be written in form of $2^p$ and Given answer is $5$. Can anyone here Help me solve this problem

Comment: The question is hard to follow.  In the unordered case, what does $\max(X)>\min (Y)$ mean?  Which is $X$ and which is $Y$?

Comment: The official count is also hard to reconcile....if $\min (Y)=1$ then any non-empty subset works for $X$, other than $Y$  or $\{1\}$, so that's a lot more than $32$ cases already.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: I removed unordered part

Comment: @lulu It is given in some test series so answer may be wrong. Other than that is my solution correct

Comment: I can't understand your solution at all.  What is $m$?  Why should $X$ have the form $\{1,2,3, \cdots, m\}$?  There are lots of subsets of $A$ that aren't of that form.  And, as I say, unless I am misreading the question, the answer is *much* greater than $2^5=32$.

Comment: $m$ is any element from $set \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ that is set of first five nutural number. and given answer is $5$ but I think given answer can be wrong because it is from test series of FIITJEE institute

Comment: So...you mean to say that $X$ is a *subset* of $\{1, \cdots m\}$?  That makes sense, but that's not what you wrote.  And,  you meant to say that $Y$ is a subset of $\{m, \cdots, 5\}$?  Or...what does $n$ mean?

Comment: what i tried is $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and I divied this set into two parts $X=\{1,2,...,m\}$ and $Y=\{m,4,5\}$ where $m<n$

Comment: And how do you get $961$ for the total number of ordered $(X,Y)$?  There are $2^5-1=31$ non-empty subsets of $A$, so the number of ordered pairs should be $31^2-31=930$, where we subtract $31$ because we must exclude the case $X=Y$.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think your idea is good, but the arithmetic is hard to follow.  The number of non empty subsets of $\{1, \cdots, m\}$ is $2^m-1$.  The number of non-empty subsets of $\{m,\cdots, 5\}$ is $2^{6-m}-1$ so you meant to sum $\sum_{m=1}^5(2^m-1)(2^{6-m}-1)=201$.  But then you need to account for the $5$ unacceptable pairs where $X=Y=\{m\}$.  Still, the answer is nowhere near $2^5=32$, so I think there must be some confusion as to the problem statement.

Comment: An aside about word order in English: "non-empty ordered pair of sets" means that the ordered pair is non-empty, i.e., that it contains two sets (which is always true as a consequence of the definition of "ordered pair"). What you mean to say is "total number of ordered pairs of non-empty sets". Other languages offer more clues as to which adjectives modify which nouns, so word order is less important. But in English we do not have those additional clues, so it becomes important that adjectives immediately preceed the nouns they modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried to solve the initial problem and obtained the answer $2\cdot 13\cdot 31$, which is not a power of $2$. My solution is as follows. For any $n\in A$ let $m_n$ (resp. $M_n$) be the number of subsets $Z$ of $A$ such that $\min Z$ (resp. $\max Z$) equals $n$. Then $M_n=2^{n-1}$, because $\max Z=n$ iff $n\in Z$ and $Z\setminus\{n\}$ is any subset of $\{1,\dots,n-1\}$. Similarly we can show that $m_n=2^{5-n}$.
Then the number of pairs $(X,Y)$ with $X,Y\subset A$ such that $\max(X)>\min(Y)$ equals
$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le 5} m_iM_j=\sum_{1\le i<j\le 5} 2^{5-i+j-1}=$$ $$
2^4\cdot \sum_{j=2}^5\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} 2^{j-i}=2^4\cdot \sum_{j=2}^5 (2^j-2)=$$ $$2^4(2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5-2\cdot 4)=16\cdot 52.$$
To take into account the condition $X\ne Y$ we have to subtract from the obtained number the number of
subsets $Z$ of $A$ such that $\max Z>\min Z$, that is $|Z|\ge 2$. This number equals $2^5-1-5=26$. Thus the final number is $16\cdot 2\cdot 26-26=31\cdot 26$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first try to find all pairs such that $max(X)\le max(Y).$ Let max$(X)$ be $m$. Thus, $X/\{m\}$ can be one of the $2^{m-1}$ subsets of $\{1, 2, ..., m-1\}$. $Y$ is one of the $2^{5-m+1}-1$ subsets of $\{m, m+1, ..., 5\}$. Out of the total of $2^{m-1}(2^{5-m+1}-1)$ pairs, exactly one is $(\{m\}, \{m\}).$

Thus, the total number of such pairs is $\sum_{i=1}^{5}(2^{m-1}(2^{5-m+1}-1)-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{5}(2^5-2^{m-1})-5=5\times 2^5-5-1-2-\dots-2^4=5\times 2^5-5-(2^5-1)=4\times 2^5-4=4\times32-4=124$

Thus, the final answer is coming to $930-124=806=2\times13\times31$, which is not a power of $2$.